# android arrayLIST of objects ksoap no llena mi listview

Tags: android, array, android-asynctask

Estoy desarrollando una app que consume webservices, el detalle es que me mandan un metodo que se llama `menu`, el cual me reponde un xml, estoy implementando la `class Asynctask` y en la parte del `Ibackgrind` hago el llamado a mi webservices y lo guardo en un array, pero despues en el `onpostexecute` llena mi `lisview`, solo que al momento en que termina de traerme los datos truena no pasa al metodo del `onpostexecute`, les dejo el error de consola:

> 04-21 14:46:38.645 18977-18977/com.example.onc_lap.proyecto I/art: Not
>   late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on) 04-21 14:46:38.771
>   18977-18977/com.example.onc_lap.proyecto W/System: ClassLoader
>   referenced unknown path:
>   /data/app/com.example.onc_lap.proyecto-1/lib/x86 04-21 14:46:38.798
>   18977-18990/com.example.onc_lap.proyecto D/OpenGLRenderer: Use
>   EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true 04-21 14:46:38.923
>   18977-18990/com.example.onc_lap.proyecto I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized
>   EGL, version 1.4 04-21 14:46:39.002
>   18977-18990/com.example.onc_lap.proyecto W/EGL_emulation:
>   eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented 04-21 14:46:39.002
>   18977-18990/com.example.onc_lap.proyecto W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to
>   set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xabdc6dc0, error=EGL_SUCCESS 04-21
>   14:46:50.246 18977-18983/com.example.onc_lap.proyecto W/art:
>   Suspending all threads took: 41.574ms 04-21 14:46:50.261
>   18977-18977/com.example.onc_lap.proyecto D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting
>   down VM 04-21 14:46:50.261 18977-18977/com.example.onc_lap.proyecto
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                 Process: com.example.onc_lap.proyecto, PID: 18977
>                                                                                 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.app.ProgressDialog.dismiss()' on a null object reference
>                                                                                     at
>   com.example.onc_lap.proyecto.menu$AsyncCallWSMenu.onPostExecute(menu.java:86)
>                                                                                     at
>   com.example.onc_lap.proyecto.menu$AsyncCallWSMenu.onPostExecute(menu.java:52)
>                                                                                     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:651)
>                                                                                     at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(AsyncTask.java)
>                                                                                     at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:668)
>                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 04-21
>   14:47:33.805 18977-18977/com.example.onc_lap.proyecto I/Process:
>   Sending signal. PID: 18977 SIG: 9

codigo **activiy:**

```
package com.example.onc_lap.proyecto;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by ONC-LAP on 19/04/2016.
 */
public class menu extends Activity {

    Button btnmenu;
    String ResultMenu;
    ProgressDialog dialog;
    ListView list;

    ArrayAdapter<String>  arrayadapter;
    ArrayList MenuArrayList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.menu);

        list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listmenu);

        btnmenu = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnmenu);
        btnmenu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                AsyncCallWSMenu task = new AsyncCallWSMenu();
                //Call execute
                task.execute();

            }
        });
        {

        }

    }

    private class AsyncCallWSMenu extends AsyncTask<String, ArrayList, menuxml> {

        List<String> arraylist = new ArrayList<String>();

        @Override
        protected menuxml doInBackground(String... params)         {
            MenuArrayList=webService.Menu();
            menuxml n = new menuxml();
            return n;
        }

        @Override
        //Make Progress Bar visible
        protected void onPreExecute() {
/*
            dialog=new ProgressDialog(menu.this);
            dialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            dialog.setMessage("Loding...");
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
            dialog.show();
*/
        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... params) {
        }


        //Once WebService returns response
        protected void onPostExecute(menuxml n) {


            super.onPreExecute();
            // tv.setText(displayText);
            if(MenuArrayList.size()!=0){
                dialog.dismiss();
                arrayadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(menu.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1, arraylist );
                list.setAdapter(arrayadapter);
            }else{
                dialog.dismiss();

            }

        }
    }
}
```

**webservices:**

```
public static ArrayList Menu() {

        // Create request
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject("http://oncontrol.no-ip.net:9020/","Menu");
        // Property which holds input parameters

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.implicitTypes=false;
        // Set output SOAP object
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        // Create HTTP call object
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL,7000);

        ArrayList MenuArray = new ArrayList();
        //ArrayAdapter<String>  arrayadapter;
        try {
            androidHttpTransport.debug=true;
            // Invoke web service
            androidHttpTransport.call("http://oncontrol.no-ip.net:9020/Menu", envelope);
            String ss=androidHttpTransport.responseDump;
            // Get the response
           // SoapObject obj1 = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
           // SoapObject obj2 = (SoapObject) obj1.getProperty(0);
            SoapObject response = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();

            SoapObject obj1 = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();

            SoapObject obj2 =(SoapObject) obj1.getProperty(1);

            SoapObject obj3 =(SoapObject) obj2.getProperty(0);

            for(int i=0; i<obj3.getPropertyCount(); i++)
            {
                SoapObject obj4 =(SoapObject) obj3.getProperty(i);
                int id= Integer.parseInt(obj4.getProperty("Id").toString());
                String Descripcion = obj4.getProperty("Descripcion").toString();
                MenuArray.add(i,Descripcion);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            //Assign Error Status true in static variable 'errored'
            //menu.errored = true;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //Return booleam to calling object
        //return loginStatus;

        return MenuArray;
    }
}
```

ya modifique mi activity pero aun asi se salta el onpostexecute dejo mi codigo como lo tengo ya modificado

```
    private class AsyncCallWSMenu extends AsyncTask<String, ArrayList, ArrayList> {



            @Override
            protected ArrayList doInBackground(String... params)         {
                MenuArrayList=webService.Menu();

                return "";
            }

            @Override
            //Make Progress Bar visible
            protected void onPreExecute() {
    /*
                dialog=new ProgressDialog(menu.this);
                dialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                dialog.setMessage("Loding...");
                dialog.setCancelable(false);
                dialog.show();
    */
            }

/*            @Override
            protected void onProgressUpdate(ArrayList... values) {
                super.onProgressUpdate(values);
            }*/

            //Once WebService returns response
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList arrayList) {
                if (MenuArrayList.size() !=0){
                    arrayadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(menu.this,
                            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1, arraylist);
                    list.setAdapter(arrayadapter);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error principal es :

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.app.ProgressDialog.dismiss()' on a null object reference at

es debido a que tratas de ejecutar el método dismiss() en una instancia nula de `dialog` :

```
dialog.dismiss();
```

ya que tienes comentada la creación del ProgressDialog :

```
dialog=new ProgressDialog(menu.this);
```

#### -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

Para lograr que tu ListView tenga valores, asegura que MenuArrayList contenga datos dentro de `onPostExecute()`,

```
   if(MenuArrayList.size()!=0){
                dialog.dismiss();
           arrayadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                 this, 
                 android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                 MenuArrayList ); //* no se usa your_array_list
           list.setAdapter(arrayadapter);
            }else{
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
```

Comment: ya lo quite eso. ya no me manda error, volvi a ejecutar mi app pero ahora le doy click en el boton y no hace nada ni manda ya error, lo que hice fue debuggear y si me traen los datos que necesito y me lo aguarda en mi arraylist, pero cuando termina de ejecutarse el doIbackground no pasa al onposexecute que es donde se tiene formar mi listview, que podra ser?

Comment: Hugo acabo de ver, recuerda que debes sobreescribir los métodos, agrega  @ arriba de protected eso puede ser la causa que no se ejecute onPostExecute(). Además tienes un super.onPreExecute(); dentro de onPostExecute() lo cual es incorrecto !!!

Comment: ya modifique los datos, pero aun asi se sigue pasando el onPosExecute

Comment: trata con los cambios que modifique en tu respuesta, he visto que tienes muchas preguntas y ninguna tiene la solución tu pregunta generalmente se refiere a una solución pero tienes errores de otro tipo, te aconsejaría realizaras preguntas paso a paso.

Comment: ok, hare la prueba con su cambio, ahorita le notifico

Comment: ya funciono muchas gracias por la correcion, otra pregunta para que me aparesca mi listview sin necesidad de que dar click en el boton el excecute lo tendria que poner fuera del boton?

Comment: Si te sirvió la respuesta no olvides marcarla como aceptada ok :). Si tendría que estar fuera, pero recuerda que unicamente se llenaría de datos al dar clic en el botón ya que este es el que obtiene los datos y actualiza el adapter:  list.setAdapter(arrayadapter);